# 'was' versus 'had been'

Tags: tense, exam-questions, past-vs-past-perfect

> When I asked the driver/ to come with me to the temple/ he had been reluctant./ No error.

I think instead of 'had been', there should be 'was'. Even the answer key points that the error is in the 'he had been reluctant' part. But I am not sure why exactly is 'had been' wrong.

If we replace the first part with 'when I had asked the driver', would that make 'had been' in the third part correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [past perfect tense](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/pastpf.htm) ("had been") when you are trying to show which of two events in the past happened first. *"He had been reluctant when I asked him to come with me"* indicates his reluctance came first, which doesn't seem right.

*"He had been reluctant to go to the temple, but came with me when I asked."*  or *"When I asked him to come with me, he was reluctant."* makes more sense. The "when" indicates the time that the events happened (at the same time that I asked), so the past perfect tense isn’t needed.