# Money was handed over / money had been handed over

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

The money was handed over to driver by this morning

Money had been handed over to driver this morning

What is the difference between these sentences?

Comment: Please do a search. There are many questions that ask the difference between the past and the past perfect.

Comment: First of all, both of them should have "**the**" before "**driver**". Second, the second sentence implies that another action took place after the money was given and before now - it's far deeper into the past.

Comment: Related: ['was' versus 'had been'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32683/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have doubts about the correctness of both the original sentences.
But I would use "The money had been handed over to the driver this morning" (past perfect) to refer to something happened before something else that we are talking about, like in "They didn't give me the money because it had been given to the driver this morning".
Or I would use "The money was handed over to driver this morning" (simple past) to describe something happened this morning

Answer (score 0):

> Money had been handed over to driver this morning

The above sentence simply shows that the task of handing over the money to the driver has already been carried out this morning.

> The money was handed over to driver by this morning

Now, I am not very sure about the correctness of this sentence, possible alternates are :

> 1.The money was handed over to the driver this morning

or

> 2.The money was to be handed over to the driver by this morning

There is no difference between the sentences, other than your usage preference if you select option 1.

However, option 2 shows that there was a plan of handing over the money to the driver this morning. The task itself may or may not have been carried out.